# isomorphic reactjs cdn assets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, cdn

So I'm almost done with my first (isomorphic) ReactJS and when we deployed it, it was kinda slow to finish `build.js`. One suggestion was to use CDN to separate asset fetching (cdn0, cdn1, cdn2...) and I was wondering how I'd do that in my site. Locally my structure is

```
- build/
- config/
  - webpack-development.config.js
  - webpack-production.config.js
- node_modules/
- package.json
- public/
  - assets/ // (this is where my assets are)
    - css/
    - img/
  - build.js
- README.md
- src/
- views/
```

and my `index.ejs` is like this now

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/ico-a-brain.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/all.css">
    <!-- bunch more assets here -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = <%- JSON.stringify(initialState) %>;
    </script>

    <div id="app"><%- markup %></div>
    <script src="build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and some components that has images

```
import React from 'react';

export default class HiwComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main className="box-960 box-center"> 

        <h1 className="mt-64">How It Works</h1>

        <ul id="how">
          <li>
            <img src="assets/img/ico-how-time.svg" onError={() => { this.onerror=null; this.src='assets/img/ico-how-time.png' }} alt="Pick" />
            <p><b>Pick</b> a time</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="assets/img/ico-how-plane.svg" onError={() => { this.onerror=null; this.src='assets/img/ico-how-plane.png' }} alt="Send" />
            <p><b>Send</b> request</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

How do I start changing this to use CDN? Do you guys use some package to handle it? Basically I think it should be like locally it would still be using `./assets/css/some.css` and `./assets/img/some.jpg` and when in production it would look at maybe `http://cdn0.amazon.com/assets/css/some.css` or `http://cdn1.amazon.com/assets/img/some.jpg`

Comment: If the bottleneck is loading time of build.js then have you considered using code-splitting to load only the minimal functionality upfront and rest of features on demand .

Comment: What is code-splitting? That might be useful as well. But now it's not really the `build.js` now. There's already a bunch of assets we could show in different cdn's now.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE 2:

if you want to randomly replace path with a cdn url (as per your question below) you could easily modify the path replace plugin script to allow that feature.

I created a quick example for you, based on the [path-replace-plugin source code](https://github.com/cvgellhorn/path-replace-loader/blob/master/index.js)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileExists = require('file-exists');
var loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');
var CDNs = [
  '//cdn0.amazon.com',
  '//cdn1.amazon.com',
  '//cdn2.amazon.com',
];

module.exports = function(source) {
this.cacheable && this.cacheable();
var options = loaderUtils.parseQuery(this.query);

    if (this.resourcePath.indexOf(options.path) > -1) {
        var cdn = CDNs[Math.floor(Math.random()*CDNs.length)];
        var newPath = this.resourcePath.replace(options.path, cdn + options.replacePath);
        if (fileExists(newPath)) {
            // Introduce file to webpack in order to make them watchable
            this.dependency(newPath);
            return fs.readFileSync(newPath);
        }
    }

    return source;
};

module.exports.raw = true;
```

### UPDATE:

An even simpler way is to use the [path replace plugin](https://github.com/cvgellhorn/path-replace-loader) in Webpack. That way you don’t have to add any complexity to your JS code

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'path-replace?path=assets&replacePath=//cdn.amazon.com/assets'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I hope that helps.

--

(original answer)

If you use Webpack then your prod build can inject a flag (variable) that you can use in the app to know if you're in prod or develop.

Even this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: '"production"'
  },
  __DEV__: false,
```

Now that you know that you can use it in your custom function `getImageUrl()` that you can share via JS modules.

**environment.js**

```
function getImageUrl() {
    return __DEV__ ? '/' : '//cdn.amazon.com/';
}

export const imgUrl = getImageUrl();
```

**HiwComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { imgUrl } from './environment';

export default class HiwComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main className="box-960 box-center"> 

        <h1 className="mt-64">How It Works</h1>

        <ul id="how">
          <li>
            <img src={`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-time.svg`} onError={() => { this.onerror=null; this.src=`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-time.png` }} alt="Pick" />
            <p><b>Pick</b> a time</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src={`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-plane.svg`} onError={() => { this.onerror=null; this.src=`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-plane.png` }} alt="Send" />
            <p><b>Send</b> request</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I have implemented something like this right now. I created an `<ImgComponent file="..." />` now to handle path building like when it's local just to `/assets` and if it's production do `cdn{0-3}.amazon.com/assets`. Can I achieve `cdn{0-3}` (random or calculated) with `path-replace-plugin`?

Comment: I added an update to reflect that case. It's just an example, i bet you can make it much better, based on your needs

Comment: I see. And then I'd still use the `loaders` part of your answer? I haven't tried any of this yet. Is it this article - https://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-loader.html?

Comment: Does this also mean that it would compile with the same `cdnX` links? Haven't tried it yet sorry.

Comment: you're right. You would still use loaders, just point it to your custom one. You can use your loader for production, and not use it in development.

Comment: Apparently `path-replace-plugin` is to change actual files path. But I've learned it and modified it with reference to https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader. But now I have problem, `warning.js:44 Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid.` seems replacement only happens on client and not on server. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about static assets like Javascript, CSS and Image files the best solution would be to manage the images with CSS.

Instead of carrying the CDN domain/path with your webpack configuration and concatenate it in build time to your reactjs code like [grgur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857756/grgur) suggested:

```
<ul id="how">
  <li>
    <img src={`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-time.svg`} onError={() => { this.onerror=null; this.src=`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-time.png` }} alt="Pick" />
    <p><b>Pick</b> a time</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src={`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-plane.svg`} onError={() => { this.onerror=null; this.src=`${imgUrl}assets/img/ico-how-plane.png` }} alt="Send" />
    <p><b>Send</b> request</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think is better to manage the absolute path of the images using CSS, suppose you're using SASS and your assets directory structure in the CDN is like this:

- http://cdn0.amazon.com/assets/css/some.css
- http://cdn0.amazon.com/assets/img/ico-how-time.svg
- http://cdn0.amazon.com/assets/img/ico-how-plane.svg

**Note that is the same CDN (http://cdn0.amazon.com/)**

And the content of the some.css:

```
.box-960 {
  .mt-64 {
    #how { // BTW, avoid using ID's for CSS
      .ico-how-time {
        background-image: url(../img/ico-how-time.svg);
      }
      .ico-how-plane {
        background-image: url(../img/ico-how-plane.svg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll be making reference to the images independently of the domain/CDN/folder and the one change you need to do in the react code is to use the CSS classes instead of putting the image path + name:

```
<ul id="how">
  <li>
    <div className="ico-how-time" />
    <p><b>Pick</b> a time</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div className="ico-how-plane" />
    <p><b>Send</b> request</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also you have to figure out the rest of the styles of the images to make it look as if you were using an IMG tag, i.e. height, width, etc.

It's what comes to mind.

Comment: This could work but it could have a lot of changes because I only get my assets (and html) from a different person. Also, it would be better if I could change cdn0 to other one's like cdn1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Yeah, it depends a lot of the way you distribute the assets.